# Conditional with list comprehension (NOT list comprehension with conditional) in python

Tags: python, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

Just thought I would specify in the title, because I have found the latter all over the internet, but not the former. I am curious how to get a conditional that contains a list comprehension working in python. Specifically, I am curious about how to do something like the following:

```
if (abs(value - any_x)) > 100 for any_x in x:
```

Essentially,  I want the program to proceed if the absolute value of the difference between the value and any value in the x array is greater than 100. But the syntax as it stands is incorrect. What exactly am I missing? Thanks and best regards,

-AA

Comment: You don't *need a list comprehension*. You aren't creating a `list`, which is what list comprehensions are for. A naive loop would be better, or you can use a generator expression and `any`, so `any(abs(value - e) > 100 for e in x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `any`:

```
if any(abs(value - any_x) > 100 for any_x in x):
    ...
```

Don't use a list comprehension here as any will return `True` on the first `True` value it finds. Thus providing it a generator is the most efficient method as it will be lazily evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

---

You can use [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any).

```
if any(abs(value - any_x) > 100 for any_x in x):
```

Comment: I don't disagree with you, but the OP did ask for that specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple,

```
True in [abs(k-value)>100 for k in x]
```

Comment: Inefficient though. If the list contains a million items and the first item satisfies the condition it will still unnecessarily check all items.